# 技術的な質問(HTTP) Technical question

Tags: translation

HTTPリクエストについての書類を翻訳している。（和ー＞英）
ここにはGETのために「要求」とPOSTのために「通知」を利用されている

英語ではGETとPOSTは両方は"Request"だけど「要求」はRequestとして翻訳している

質問は「通知」はどうやって翻訳したらいい？　「Submission」？？

I am trying to translate a document regarding HTTP operations from japanese to english. 
Here they use 要求for GET and 通知for POST
I am translating 要求as request (although both are requests) but I can't figure it out how to translate 通知
automatic translation gives "Notification Report" but that does not sound natural

How about "Submission" for「通知」?

Comment: How come they're not just called GET and POST? Who is the document for?

Comment: 通知 is *notification*, but I feel you are mixing HTTP verbs (like `GET`, `PUT`) and ordinary words. HTTP verbs are almost never translated. One may decide to use POST requests to send some 通知, but POST and 通知 are not synonyms. Please include the whole sentence (or paragraph) if you're not sure.

Comment: I will give an example. For the "Machine Status Request"(機器ステータス要求）they specify that this operation uses the GET "method" And for the 印字データ通知they specify that it uses the POST method. I am trying to translate 印字データ通知。 I am going for Print Data Submission. How about that?

Comment: Ah, okay, now I think I understand your point.

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward literal translation of 通知 is *notification* in IT contexts. For example, see [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/notification) of browsers. 通知する is *to notify*. I recommend you stick to *notification* as long as it makes sense. "Print data notification" should be fine.